# When using lenses on an adapter: how to set exposure metadata manually?

Tags: metadata, adapter

I'm using a different brand of lens and body, with an adapter to make them fit. The adapter does not transfer any data from the lens to the camera, so in Lightroom, I am missing the information on focal length, apperture, lens name and probably some more.

Is there a way to write these metadata manually after importing to Lightroom? For example when I shot a session with only a 50mm prime, I know that information and would like to have it available in LR, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a Lightroom plugin called [LensTagger](http://www.essl.de/wp/software/lenstagger-lightroom-plugin/). I believe it was designed by Dirk Essl to tag digitized/scanned images that were taken with film equipment, so there are fields for film and camera as well as lens information.  It relies upon the ever-useful and ubiquitous perl-based [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) by Phil Harvey.

It's a little cumbersome, in that you have to save the changes to the EXIF in the files after you've written them (and this can, depending on the camera model and how edits are recorded, wipe out any edits you've made). But it lets you save presets, so you don't have to individually fill in every field for a specific lens (i.e., lens name, focal length, max. aperture, aperture setting, etc. etc.) each time you want to apply it.

Comment: Ok, this is of course even easier than my solution, when using Lightroom. Especially like the preset function; lenses will of course stay the same!

Answer (score 1):

Just learned it. Oh well:

- use ExifTool and maybe ExifToolGui
- write all changes to the metadata you want
- don't forget to "read metadate from file" in Lightroom, otherwise the changes won't show

The last step undoes all changes previously made on the image, so a good idea is to "write metadata to file" in Lightroom before making any changes with ExifTool.